# Rasberry Pi for a tractor

Tags: gpio, sensor, electronics

I am just starting Raspberry Pi and I am far from being a guru in electronics.

I want to know:

1. Is Raspberry Pi shock proof? Can it handle vibrations and bumps? I have seen some dust proof containers on the net.
2. Can I pick up (weak) electrical pulses (from magnets) and turn them into a digital readout?
3. Can I connect any pressure transmitter (e.g. [Omni Instruments Pi6010LP-200barA PRESSURE TRANSMITTER 10-32V 4-20MA](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Omni-Instruments-Pi6010LP-200barA-PRESSURE-TRANSMITTER-10-32V-4-20MA-/111773141462?hash=item1a0632c9d6:g:tBsAAOSwsB9V-QiW)) to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Given that they have been sent into spaceand been used in cars as medfia players etc. I don't think your tractor will represent a vibrational challenge.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I think you haven't spent enough time on tractors -- although I imagine the new ones are significantly better (and have onboard electronics of their own), there are plenty of people around who take pride in maintaining and using tractors that are older than either of us and there's a pretty wide range of potential vibrations involved with them, lol.

Comment: The Pis that have been shot into space were I think clad in styrofoam and only had to work for a few hours.  If this is a [Case 400](http://www.tractordata.com/farm-tractors/000/4/6/465-ji-case-400.html) or something I would go with clamping something dampening firmly around any connector then lots of bubble wrap, duct tape, and springs. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dust-proof and vibration-proof are different things. Generally speaking, the Pi is an electronics board with surface-mounted components and no moving parts, meaning it should be able to handle moderate vibrations, like your typical smartphone or any other electronic device.

As for your detecting electrical pulses and making a digital readout, or your pressure transmitter for that matter, that's exactly what the GPIO pins are for. If you search around, you can most likely find someone who has already done exactly what you are wanting to do and just replicate it. Things to consider are operating voltages of your sensors and any drivers that may be needed. You will probably not be able to connect "just any sensor from ebay," but there's most likely a sensor out there that works with the Raspberry Pi for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a pi case with some extra protection layer.
Raspberry pi does not come with any vibration or dust proof layer. But you can make it work. I made my scooter electrical using Raspberry pi, hall effect sensor A1332 and a hbridge. So hall effect sensor used to read the speed and in the gas paddle. so to protect our circuit we put it into a plastic Pi case with extra protection foam.
the only issue you will face is wiring. so i will suggest get modular breakout board. 
To read pressure i will suggest go with AMS5812 pressure sensor. its highly accurate and gives digital output. so no need to get any extra electronic for pressure measurement.
if you are looking for video tutorials you can find over here.

for A1332 please visit this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IecaREtTyk

For AMS5812 pressure sensor please visit this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XYvlHEUiaI

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, in my opinion it is quiet shock proof. I have dropped raspi accidentally many times and nothing happened. It works fine. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

4-20mA sensors are designed to work with analogue current sensing rather than digital or analogue voltage sensing inputs you'll more commonly find interfaced to the pi. You are probably better off finding a different sensor, unless you also want to get a 24V supply for it (you might be OK with 12V with that one though), a current to voltage converter, then an analogue to digital converter to talk to the pi's digital io pins.